MS Access Auto Numbering for field in VBA with certain format
I have a database with each customer numbered 01,02,03, etc. For a quotation number, I want it to generate according to that and date and, numbering at the end 01,02,03 and start over on each new day. Example for customer 2 for today's first quotation, I want the code to come out as: Q0225042401. The second one for that today would be Q02225042402. Then first quotation tomorrow would be Q0226042401, if you know what I mean.  I have part of the code as follows:
QNumber = "Q" & Format(Me![CustomerID], "00") & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy") 
rs("QuotationNumber") = QNumber

How should I write the code?

This is a common topic. Google "Access VBA generate unique custom identifier". https://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=23329

Does this answer your question? How to set custom ID field?

Sorry the custom ID field is a bit complicated to me. If I simplify my request, where the code is going to be: "Q" & [customerID] & year (24) & 3 digit continuous number (001), i.e. Q0224001, and the final 3 digit goes back to 001 when its year 2025, how should I write my VBA code?

I think that you should not mess with the Auto number field .
You can have a different field and just fill it with vba.
I think this vba code should do the trick.
I didn't test it but I do believe it will work.
Dim tVar As Variant
QNumber = "Q" & Format(Me![CustomerID], "00") & Format(Now(), "ddmmyy")
tVar = DLast("[QuotationNumber]", "someTableName", "[QuotationNumber] like '" & QNumber & "*'")

If IsNull(tVar) Then
 ' no record found so it's a new day
   QNumber = QNumber & "01"
Else
'  There is a previous record for this customer and this day so just add one
   QNumber = QNumber & Format(Val(Right(tVar, 2)) + 1, "00")
End If
 rs("QuotationNumber") = QNumber

